# If Else not being recognized

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a form in which the user inputs a number, and I want my macro to check whether the number exists in a specific list in order to do some stuff. Here's how I did it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Dim number As Integer, i As Integer
 For i = 10 To 10020
     If TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
         number = TextBox1.Value
     End If
 Next i
     MsgBox "A dica número " & TextBox1.Value & " não consta na lista.", vbOKOnly, "Dica não encontrada!"
     Exit Sub

 'Do the rest of the code here
End Sub
```

The thing is: no matter what number I input, the message box always comes up. `number = TextBox1.Value` is never read.
I've tried manually checking if the values were the same for a specific input with message boxes, and even though they were the same, If/Else was never accessed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put `Exit For` inside your `If` statement.

Comment: There's actually no `ElseIf` in your code. There's also no reason to have `'Do the rest of the code here` because the `Exit Sub` will prevent execution from ever reaching that point.

Comment: @Luis The code you wrote *requires* the message box to always come up. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, the number entered in the TextBox would be considered as a String not a number. So you will need to convert it into a number and to do that, try this...

```
If Val(Me.TextBox1.Value) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
```

Second thing, you don't need to loop through the cells just to check whether the number entered in the TextBox is found in a certain range. You may utilize the CountIf function to do that like below example.

```
If Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("B10:B10020"), Me.TextBox1.Value) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! The `.CountIf` did a better job than `If`.

Comment: @LuisEduardo note that `Application.CountIf` is the late-bound equivalent of the early-bound `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` - the latter will happily compile a typo, the former gives you intellisense, compile-time validation, and trappable run-time errors given invalid arguments.